# Properties of a relation on matrices: $(m_1,m_2)\in R$ iff $m_1\cdot m_2$ is defined

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let $M$ be a set of matrices of integers.
Let $R$ be the relation on $M$ defined as follows: For any two $m_1, m_2 \in M, (m_1, m_2) \in R$ iff the
matrix multiplication $m_1 \cdot m_2$ is defined.

Part (a) - 
Given any element $m_1 \in M$, suppose that
$(m_1, m_1) \in R$.
What does that tell you about the shape of $m_1$?

For this part I'm pretty confident that the shape is a square.

Part (b) - 
Suppose that the elements of $M$ are chosen such that $R$ is reflexive. Explain
why it must be true that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 1):

From part (a), you know all the elements of $M$ are square matrices. You just need to show that the relation is therefore symmetric and transitive.

---

Adding more detail:

We know all elements of $M$ are square matrices.

Symmetry: If $(m_1, m_2) \in R$, then the matrix multiplication $m_1 m_2$ is defined. Therefore both matrices must be the same size ($n \times n$ for some $n$). What can you conclude about $(m_2, m_1)$?

Transitivity: If $(m_1, m_2) \in R$, then by the same argument, $m_1$ and $m_2$ must be the same size ($n \times n$ for some $n$). Similarly if $(m_2, m_3) \in R$, then $m_2$ and $m_3$ are the same size. What can you say about $(m_1, m_3)$?

Comment: Since it's reflexive we can say it is $(a,a) \in R$.  Symmetry is $(b,a) ~ when~ (a,b) \in R$, but since its $(a,a) \in R$ that also makes it symmetric and the fact its a square.  Then for Transitivity since its for any two $m_1, m_2$ we can say that there is a element in between them $m_{1.5}$ that we can say which they are all related to each other? Any nudges into the right direction would be awesome

Comment: @Helpless I don't understand your comment at all

Comment: @Helpless see my edits above

Comment: Thank you so much! That is kind of what I was thinking about I just didn't know how start it and word it properly.